# Object material does not change in opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I need to change the ball material to chrome. I found the values ​​for chrome in one book, entered them, and nothing changed for the ball - it is just a standard white color.

This is what the ball turns out to be:

[image: here]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void init(void)
{
    GLfloat mat_ambient[] = {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = {0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = {0.774597, 0.774597, 0.774597, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_shininess = 76.8;
    GLfloat light_position[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);


    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSolidSphere(1.0, 100, 16);
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, static_cast<GLsizei>(w), static_cast<GLsizei>(h));
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w <= h)
        glOrtho(-1.5, 1.5, -1.5 * static_cast<GLfloat>(h) / static_cast<GLfloat>(w),
                1.5 * static_cast<GLfloat>(h) / static_cast<GLfloat>(w), -10.0, 10.0);
    else
        glOrtho(-1.5 * static_cast<GLfloat>(w) / static_cast<GLfloat>(h),
                1.5 * static_cast<GLfloat>(w) / static_cast<GLfloat>(h), -1.5, 1.5, -10.0, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what were the original values?

Comment: These values ​​were given to me in the manual for my laboratory work. I was just able to solve the problem by commenting out the line glEnable (GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
However, I don't understand why everything works without this line.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks to you, I figured out

Comment: [Basic OpenGL Lighting](https://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html)